# Recover deleted Power Automation aka Microsoft Flow

Tags: powershell, power, microsoft-flow

Is there a way to recover deleted Power Automation Flows?

I know that there is a PowerShell to recover PowerApps. I tried changing the syntax of the `Get-Verb` to flow instead of PowerApp, but no luck

```
Get-AdminRecoverDeletedPowerApp -AppName [Guid] -EnvironmentName [Guid]
Get-AdminRecoverDeletedFlow -AppName [Guid] -EnvironmentName [Guid]
```

Comment: Thank you @VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle. I will update that as a self answer if I can figure out how

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer per the below source referenced post but it was this command:

```
Restore-AdminFlow -EnvironmentName Default-GUID -FlowName GUID
```

> ### Steps to Restore the Flow(s)
>
> - Sign in to Power Platform Environment using the below code
> - Login screen pops-up
> - Provide user name and password to connect to the Power Platform environment where Flow/App needs to be restored
>
> `Add-PowerAppsAccount`
>
> - Run the below code to get the list of deleted Flows within the last 28 days
>
> ```
> -IncludeDeleted $true Get-AdminFlow -EnvironmentName Default-31fd69b3-0535-4506-8d24-6674fc42002b -IncludeDeleted $true
> ```
>
> - You can get the Environment name from the Power Automate Flow URL
> - It lists out all the deleted Flow(s)
> - Select the FlowName which you want to restore
> - Run the below code to restore the deleted Flow
>
> ```
> //Restore-AdminFlow -EnvironmentName 'Environment Name' -FlowName 
> 'Flow Name which you want to restore' Restore-AdminFlow
> -EnvironmentName Default-31fd69b3-0535-4506-8d24-6674fc42002b -FlowName  43e8eda9-bd55-47e0-8bc8-9ecdf864f55c
> ```
>
> - Navigate to the Power Automate Portal Page & Check the Flow
> - Flow might have been restored and it will be in disabled mode
> - Turn on the Flow to run
>
> ### Restore Deleted Power Apps
>
> - Signin to Power Platform Environment : Add-PowerAppsAccount
> - Run the code to list out all the deleted Power apps
> - Get the Power App Name from the listing which you want to restore
> - Run the code to restore the Power app
> - Check the Power App Portal
> - App might have been restored with the name appended with "`_RestoredYYYYMMDDHHMM`'
>
> ### Points to remember
>
> - The above steps will work only to restore non-solution flows/apps. If you deleted a flow/app that was part of a solution, you need to create a support ticket with Microsoft for assistance.
> - Flows that have been deleted more than 28 days ago can’t be recovered, neither with PowerShell script nor Microsoft support
>
> [Source](https://rajasubr.com/2022/07/19/restore-the-deleted-power-automate-flows-power-apps/)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).